# Conditional formatting based on data from multiple cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I hate to even ask, but I seem to be stumped. We run reports daily and export to Excel. These reports return at least 35,000 records and each record has data filled in columns A-AJ. Each record is considered an element and are part of a group (of either 2, 3 or 4 elements). These 2, 3 or 4 assets share the same Asset ID (column Q). There is information in column P, which, for this exercise will say "To Be Deleted", that needs to be highlighted, so that we can pull those by themselves and look at them based on their color, or delete them outright from our report. The issue that I'm having difficulty with is that there are multiple elements associated with each asset ID, but in column P, it will only say "To be deleted" on an individual element, and will not highlight every element associated with the asset ID. (So, I think that's a better way to phrase my query) I need to be able to highlight every element (in each instance it shows up in column Q) that the phrase "To be deleted" shows up in column P.

For example, there is a box, a barrel and a trailer. If the trailer for asset ID 78525 comes up "to be deleted", I want to be able to highlight (the entire row) everything that has the asset ID 78525 (which would also include the box and the barrel as well). I apologize if this sounds a bit convoluted, but the only other way I see to do this is by hand, every time I see "to be deleted", I will have to manually highlight that row and every row of the affiliated asset ID. If anyone has any workarounds using conditional formatting, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula-based CF rule using COUNTIFS()

See below for a simplified example. ColC has the same formula used in the CF rule.

[image]